# Importing iTunes library in any Ubuntu music player

Tags: rhythmbox, music-player, itunes, amarok

I'm trying to migrate my iTunes library, in particular the ratings, to Ubuntu.

I've tried various music players but so far had no luck. Clementine doesn't have anything to import iTunes ratings, Amarok has an old script that no longer work, and for Rhythmbox I'd need to install a MySQL server.

Is there any player that has a built-in solution or working plugin? Or maybe there's a simpler way with the players above?

Answer (score 0):

Download [this](http://dwelle.org/eg/transferratingsperl.zip) file and extract it to your home folder.

Install `perl`

`sudo apt-get install perl`

Type the following command -

`perl transferratings.pl path/to/itunes.xml path/to/rhythmbdb.xml`

The location of `rhythmdb.xml` can be found using

`locate rhythmdb.xml`